# Prove: For all integers $a$, $b$, and $c$, if $a \mid b$ and $b \mid c$ then $a \mid (3b-2c)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I keep getting this answer and I am not sure if it is correct using these steps.
By definition of divides, $b = ar$ and $c=bs$ for some integers $r$ and $s$.

1. By definition of divides, $b = ar$ and $c=bs$ for some integers $r$ and $s$.
2. Then, $(3b-2c) = 3(ar) - 2(bs)$
3. $= 3ar-2bs$
4. Let $x = 3ar-2bs$
5. Thus, $3b-2c= ax$ where $x$ is an integer.
6. By definition of divides, then, $a \mid (3b-2c)$ as was shown.

My question is: is this logic sound and if not, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your 5 is wrong: you aree writing that $3b-2c=a(3b-2c).$

Comment: You may wish to check your definition of $x$ on line 4. Because the current $x$ doesn't satisfy $3b-2c=ax$ on line 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\ a \mid b\ $ then $\ a \mid 3b.$ Let $ ka = 3b,\ k\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Also,  $\ a \mid c\ $ and so $\ a \mid 2c.\ $ Let $ma = 2c,\ m\in\mathbb{Z}.$

$3b-2c = ka-ma=(k-m)a,\ $ and since $\ k,m\in\mathbb{Z},\ k-m\in\mathbb{Z}.\ $

So $3b-2c$ is a multiple of $a.$

Answer (score 0):

Let me modify your writing as little as possible.

1. By definition of divides, $b=ar$ and $c=bs$ for some integers $r$ and $s.$
2. Then, $3b−2c=3b-2bs=b(3-2s)$
3. $=ar(3-2s).$
4. Let $x=r(3-2s).$
5. Thus, $3b-2c= ax$ where $x$ is an integer.
6. By definition of divides, then, $a \mid (3b-2c)$ as was to show.